Submitting Form Opens PHP Page, PHP Page Isn't Working
I'm trying to allow form submission for the website that I'm developing, but the form opens the PHP page and gives HTTP Error 405. How do I fix this?
PHP File (register.php):
<?php
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogin';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset() function will check if the data exists.
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    exit('Please complete the registration form!');
}
// Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // One or more values are empty.
    exit('Please complete the registration form');
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['username']) == 0) {
        exit('Username is not valid!');
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
        exit('Password must be between 5 and 20 characters long!');
    }if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        exit('Email is not valid!');
    }
}// We need to check if the account with that username exists.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // Username already exists
        echo 'Username exists, please choose another!';
    } else {
        // Username doesn't exists, insert new account
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
    // We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'You have successfully registered! You can now login!';
} else {
    // Something is wrong with the SQL statement, so you must check to make sure your accounts table exists with all three fields.
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    // Something is wrong with the SQL statement, so you must check to make sure your accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
$con->close();
?>

HTML File (register.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gimkit Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="register.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://www.gimkit.com/favicon.33200140.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="register">
        <h1>REGISTER</h1>
        <form action="register.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="USERNAME" id="username" required>
            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" id="password" required>
            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" id="email" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

CSS File (register.css):
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Impact;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 1vw;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0%;
}
body {
    background-color: #435165;
    margin: 0;
}
.register {
    width: 70vw;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 8vw auto;
}
.register h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5b6574;
    font-size: 6vw;
    padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}
.register form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.register form label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 4vw;
    height: 4vw;
    background-color: #3274d6;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 4vw;
}
.register form input[type="password"], .register form input[type="text"], .register form input[type="email"] {
    width: 55vw;
    height: 4vw;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    color: #435165;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 1vw;
    margin-left: 4vw;
    margin-right: 4vw;
}
.register form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    background-color: #3274d6;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #2868c7;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

Can anyone try to test it out or find what the problem is?
I've tried editing the code, but it hasn't worked.

This is a webserver configuration problem. 405 means the POST request isn't supported.

This means your server is restricting access to that page from its source. Have you researched 405 HTTP method error message or the error it throws to you and read up on possible solutions? There is a lot of information out there on how to identify what could be causing your issue, though it is likely server configuration.

What webserver are you using to test your code?

I am using VS Code's "Live Server" to run the code onto Microsoft Edge.

OK. That explains the problem then. It's just a basic server designed for static/client-side sites. It doesn't support PHP, or even HTTP POST requests - hence the error message. You need to use a proper webserver like Apache to serve your site. You can use packages like xampp or laragon to easily set up a local development environment with php, apache and a database
